# При вызове функции не хватает аргумента

Tags: python, aiogram

При вызове функции не хватает аргумента.
Нужно что-то передать, а я без понятия, что нужно передать.

```
url = "https://www.olx.ua/uk/"
a = 5000-7000

params = {
   'q': 'iPhone 11',  # пошук
   'category_id': 25,  # ID категорії
   'per_page': 10, # кількість результатів на сторінці
   'price': a, #Ціна
}
response = requests.get(url, params=params)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("BOT START")


def get_olx_offers():
    headerss = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {api_key}'}
    response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headerss)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.text
    else:
        print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")

async def process_offers(offers):
    for offer in offers.get('data', []):
        # Перевірка, чи підходить оголошення вашим критеріям
        if 'iPhone' in offer.get('title', '').lower() and offer.get('price', 0) <= 10000:
            print("Знайдено підходяще оголошення:")
            print(f"Назва: {offer['title']}")
            print(f"Ціна: {offer['price']} грн")
            print(f"Посилання: {offer['url']}")
            print("\n")
    await asyncio.sleep(60)



async def vidpravka(vidpravkaa):
    for vidpravkaa in vidpravkaa.get('data', []):
        if 'iPhone 11' in vidpravkaa.get('title', '').lower() and vidpravkaa.get('price', 0) <= 10000:
            message = (
                f"Знайдено підходяще оголошення:\n"
                f"Назва: {vidpravkaa['title']}\n"
                f"Ціна: {vidpravkaa['price']} грн\n"
                f"Посилання: {vidpravkaa['url']}"
            )
            await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text=message)
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

```
process_offers()
TypeError: process_offers() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offer]
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Приложите код программы текстом, ваш скриншот никто рассматривать не будет.

Comment: А где вызов самой функции?

Comment: Вызов я не скопировал

Answer (score -2):

В вашем коде функция `process_offers` принимает один аргумент `offers`, но при вызове функции у вас отсутствует передача этого аргумента. Вы должны передать какой-то объект типа, ожидаемого функцией `process_offers`.

Например, если у вас есть словарь с ключом 'data', который содержит список предложений, вы можете вызвать функцию следующим образом:

```py
import asyncio

# Предположим, что у вас есть переменная offers_dict, содержащая данные
offers_dict = {
    'data': [
        {'title': 'Iphone X', 'price': 9500, 'url': 'http://example.com/iphone-x'},
        # Другие предложения
    ]
}

async def process_offers(offers):
    for offer in offers.get('data', []):
        if 'Iphone' in offer.get('title', '').lower() and offer.get('price', 0) <= 10000:
            print("Знайдено пiдходяще оголошення")
            print(f"Назва: {offer['title']}")
            print(f"Цiна: {offer['price']}")
            print(f"Посилання: {offer['url']}")
            print("\n")
    await asyncio.sleep(60)

# Передача словаря в качестве аргумента
asyncio.run(process_offers(offers_dict))
```

Здесь `offers_dict` передается в качестве аргумента функции `process_offers`. Пожалуйста, замените `offers_dict` на ваш фактический объект данных, который вы хотите обработать в функции.